# rails 4 paperclip upload to amazon s3 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have been following the rails 4 tutorial on railstutorial.org.  I have completed most of it, the project is hosted on heroku but now want to add image uploading to Amazon S3.  I have followed the guide on the heroku website but cannot get anything to upload to my bucket on S3 (Europe).

I am using paperclip 3.5.2.

**Post model**

```
  has_attached_file :post_photo,
                    styles: {
                        thumb: '100x100>',
                        square: '200x200#',
                        medium: '300x300>'
                    },
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => {
                        :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
                        :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'] },
                    :s3_protocol => "https",
                    :path => ":class/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
                    :url => ':s3_eu_url',
                    :bucket => 'bucket_name'
```

**Post Controller**

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:post_photo, :user_username, :title, :comment, :location, :user_id)
end
```

**config/initializers/Paperclip.rb**

```
Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_eu_url) { |attachment, style|
  "#{attachment.s3_protocol}://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{attachment.bucket_name}/#{attachment.path(style).gsub(%r{^/}, "")}"
}
```

**config/environment.rb**

```
require 'aws/s3'
AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST = "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
 # config/environments/production.rb
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      },
      :url => ':s3_eu_url',
      :path => ":class/:id/:basename_:style.:extension"
  }
```

Comment: are you using gem 'aws-sdk' ?

Answer (score 4):

So, I've gotten this working (not with Europe S3, but that shouldn't matter) not having anything in `config/environments/production.rb` -- mostly because I use the ENV variables to help control which bucket I'm pointing at, API keys, etc.

Here's my config:

In `config/environments/production.rb`:

Only the standard config -- nothing to do with paperclip.

In `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol] = 'http'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] =
  { :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] }
```

To the above, you'd want to add:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Then, your `Post` model should only have to have something like:

```
has_attached_file :post_photo,
                    styles: {
                        thumb: '100x100>',
                        square: '200x200#',
                        medium: '300x300>'
                    }
```

This may be obvious, but also make sure you have the `aws-sdk` gem loaded in your Gemfile.

Let me know if you have questions.  I've set this up quite a few times and will totally help troubleshoot. :)

Comment: Yes I have included aws-sdk in my gemfile, I've made the changes and it's still not uploading to my bucket.  Also, when I run heroku logs, I don't see any error messages regarding the upload to the bucket but I can see that the file is being processed by the app.

Comment: Is this in production?  Or a local environment?  Also, might be worth turning logging up to DEBUG level to see what else might be going on.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back, I haven't been able to look at this.  This is when I deploy to heroku so I guess that's production?  I'm not sure how to set up the amazon credentials for my local environment. Should I be replacing ':s3_domain_url' with 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'?